# Alexa skill rejected without feedback

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I have submitted my skill 3 times.  It stays in the in review state for a day or two then suddenly reverts back to development, without any feedback (as far as we can find).  The one thing we think may be the cause is that our app has an active beta test using the alexa beta testing feature.

Any ideas on why this is happening and what we can do.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon should be emailing you with feedback when your skill gets rejected from **no-reply-skilldev@amazon.com**, so I would search through the spam folder of whichever email account you have linked to your Alexa skill to make sure you're not just missing those messages.

After you've confirmed Amazon *isn't* sending you feedback, I'd comb through each of the certification checklists to make sure your skill meets all the criteria:

- [Policy Testing](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/alexa-skills-kit-policy-testing)
- [Security Testing](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/alexa-skills-kit-security-testing)
- [Functional Testing](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/alexa-skills-kit-functional-testing)
- [VUI / UX Testing](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/alexa-skills-kit-voice-interface-and-user-experience-testing)

I'd suggest resubmitting after going through each of those checklists, and reaching out to Amazon on the **Certification Inquiry** page on https://developer.amazon.com/support.

Best of luck!

Comment: On the 4th attempt they finally sent feedback.  The only difference was that disabled the beta test we were running.  Our feedback indicated that they had replied several times, but we never recieved any.